# XMLHttpRequest() exercise

Tags: xml, xmlhttprequest

Im calling a php file which reads in random names from a file.
I want to dynamically add names to a table. If the name is already present i want to increment the count situated in another cell next to it. There is a bug in my code and i cant find it.

here is my code

```
et button = document.querySelector("input");
let par = document.querySelector("p");
let table = document.querySelector("table");
let xhr;
let myArr=[14];
let tempStrin;

function upDateTable(name){

    for(let i=0; i < myArr.length; i++){
        if(myArr[name>=1]){
            myArr[name]++;
            document.querySelectorAll(`#${name}`).innerText = myArr[name];
        }
        else{
            myArr[name]=1;
            table.innerHTML+=`<tr><td>${name}</td><td id=${name}>${myArr[name]}</td></tr>`
        }
    }
}

function xhrCall () {

    try {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.addEventListener(`readystatechgange`, function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    tempStrin = xhr.responseText;
                    updateTable(tempStr);
                }//if
            }//if
        });//on readystatechange

    xhr.open('GET', "http://csdev.cegep-heritage.qc.ca/students/1175333/JBarbeau_C31L03_Files/php/random.php");
    xhr.send();
}
catch(e){
        console.error("Request did not work");
}

}

let testTime;
button.addEventListener('click' ()=>{
    if (button.value==="Start"){
        button.value==="Stop";
        testTime= setInterval(xhrCall,3000);
    }
    else if(button.value==="Stop"){
        button.value="Start";
        clearInterval(testTime);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel comfortable with `document.querySelectorAll('#${name}')` and I believe it is one of the reasons why it doesn't work. `querySelectorAll` will return an `HTMLCollection`, so setting `innerText` on it does not make sense. Also, you are using an Id, so it should technically be unique on your page.

Also, I think you would benefit greatly from a 'dictionary' object instead of a classic array:

```
let dict = {};

function upDateTable(name){
    //We check if our name exists
    if (dict[name]) {
        dict[name] += 1;
        document.getElementById(`#${name}`).innerText = myArr[name];
    } else {
        dict[name] = 1;
        //no reason to put our value in the string, we know it's always 1
        table.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${name}</td><td id=${name}>1</td></tr>`; 
    }
}
```